# cmd with Powershell issue

Tags: powershell, cmd, mount-diskimage

if i run my command in PowerShell all works fine. But if i run it in cmd it doesn't work.

Background: i will create a batch that works on every system that mounts an iso and then runs an exe that needs that iso. i wanna use a batch instead of a ps1 cause i am not familiar with ps1 signing and if it runs on all systems without issues.

For PowerShell
`Mount-DiskImage ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName+"\data.iso")`

For cmd
`PowerShell Mount-DiskImage ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName+"\data.iso")`

error:

```
Die Zeichenfolge hat kein Abschlusszeichen: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Comment: I dont understand how that should work. Powershell was created after cmd...therefore, Powershell knows cmd commands (not sure if all), but cmd cannot know Powershell commands.

Comment: you would need to run this in two lines, CMD cant run powershell commands. Therefore run `powershell` which will move you into powershell, then run `Mount-Disk...`

Answer (score 0):

The `\` escape can cause problems with quoted directory paths that contain a trailing backslash because the closing quote `"` at the end of the line will be escaped `\"`.

To save a directory path with a trailing backslash `(\)` requires adding a second backslash to 'escape the escape'
so for example instead of `"C:\My Docs\"` use `"C:\My Docs\\"`

[Source](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose your command(s) in curly brackets, prefix it with an ampersand (`&`) to execute it and wrap that by quotes:

```bsh
PowerShell "& {Mount-DiskImage ((Get-Item -Path .\ -Verbose).FullName+"\data.iso")}"
```

You can read more about how to call PowerShell with command line options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1).